# Combining Pandas startswith and rstrip

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare two strings, each containing an array of ints, to see if one is the start of the other. These are both columns in a pandas DataFrame. Here's the problem reduced to a simple example.

Here's the data:

```python
data = {'pred1': ['[0, 1, 2, 3]', '[0, 2, 2, 4]'], 'pred2': ['[0, 1]', '[0, 1]']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Using Pandas `rstrip` I can take the final `]` from the `pred2` column:

```python
df['pred2'].str.rstrip(']')
```

```
> 0    [0, 1  
> 1    [0, 1  
> Name: pred2, dtype: object
```

The following gives the result I would expect

```python
df['pred1'].str.startswith('[0, 1')
```

```
> 0    True
> 1    False
> Name: pred1, dtype: bool
```

But combining the Pandas `startswith` and `rstrip` across the two columns does not seem to work:

```python
df['pred1'].str.startswith(df['pred2'].str.rstrip(']'))
```

```
> 0   NaN
> 1   NaN
> Name: pred1, dtype: float64
```

```python
df['pred1'].str.startswith(str(df['pred2'].str.rstrip(']')))
```

```
> 0    False
> 1    False
> Name: pred1, dtype: bool
```

Given that the `rstrip` produces `[0, 1` for the first row in the second column, why is the resulting value for `startswith` `False`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) instead:

```
In [3793]: df.apply(lambda x: x['pred1'].startswith(x['pred2'].rstrip(']')), axis=1)
Out[3793]: 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Issue with your command `df['pred1'].str.startswith(df['pred2'].str.rstrip(']'))` is:

You are passing a `series` in `series.str.startswith` , which is not expected.

As per [`series.str.startswith docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

> pat : str
> Character sequence. Regular expressions are not accepted.

Comment: I tend to upvote immediately (as I did in this case) and wait a while before accepting the answer just in case other answers come in too

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) here.

```
pat = '|'.join(df['pred2'].str.rstrip(']')).replace('[', '\[')
pat = f"^({pat})"

df['pred1'].str.match(pat)
0     True
1    False
Name: pred1, dtype: bool
```